# Can we specify date range in flot graph time series chart?

Tags: jquery, flot

I want a line graph where the x axis is a date range, ex- Jan 13, 2014- Feb 13, 2014

Can we by any chance achieve this using flot graph(line chart).

Below is the way I'm passing the data

```
{
    "graph_data": [{
          "year": "2013",
          "data": [
            [1357065000000, 162.21],
            [1359743400000, 1742.14],
            [1362162600000, 1673.77],
            [1364841000000, 169.69],
            [1367433000000, 151.19],
            [1370111400000, 198.76],
            [1372703400000, 159.90],
            [1375381800000, 160.31],
            [1378060200000, 174.81],
            [1380652200000, 1746.58],
            [1383330600000, 171.64],
            [1385922600000, ""]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `xaxis` part of the plot options you can add minimum and maximum values for the x axis. But you have to  give these as javascript timestamps like described here in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data).

You can get timestamps for specific dates with the [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) methods:

```
(new Date(2013, 0, 13)).getTime()
```

This example gives you the timestamp for Jan 13, 2013 (the month starts with zero for January).

The complete code for the minimum and maximum values is then:

```
    xaxis: {
        min: (new Date(2013, 0, 13)).getTime(),
        max: (new Date(2013, 1, 13)).getTime(),
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
        minTickSize: [1, "day"]
    },
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sW5L/1/) for a full working example. (I used dates from 2013 since you have no data for 2014.)

Comment: You also need to add an extra field in `xaxis` i.e `timeBase: "milliseconds"`.